# Fancybox: Creating a link to a group of images without adding another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have a group of images like below:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="gym" href="DSC06334_650_480_c1.JPG">
<img width="650" height="480" alt="Golds Gym" src="DSC06334_650_480_c1.JPG">
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="gym" href="10292010.jpg">
<img width="500" height="340" alt="Golds Gym" src="10292010.jpg">
</a>
```

I'm trying to link to these images from an external link without adding another image:

```
<a data-fancybox-group="gym" class="fancybox-thumbs">More images</a>
```

The problem is, when I do this I end up with fancybox opening a blank image instead of the first image in the gallery, and an empty image in the thumbnail helper: [example](http://d.pr/i/2kHN). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are opening the fancybox on calss "fancybox-thumbs" on click event
and the More images link also have the same class so fancybox treated this as an image son it adding a blank image thumb.

Please remove the class="fancybox-thumbs" from "More Image" link, I hope blank thumb problem will resolve.

Comment: the link is no longer clickable with just `<a data-fancybox-group="gym" fancybox-thumbs">More Images</a>`

Comment: If you don't use herf attribute then link will no longer clickable.
Please use 
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-fancybox-group="gym" fancybox-thumbs">More Images</a>

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
<a class="my-class" href="imgSrc-1-big.gif" rel="fancybox-gallery-1" >
  <img src="img_thumb-0-small.gif" alt="" />
</a>

<div style="display: none;"> 
  <a class="my-class" href="imgSrc-2-big.gif" rel="fancybox-gallery-1"></a>
  <a class="my-class" href="imgSrc-3-big.gif" rel="fancybox-gallery-1"></a>
  . . .
</div>
```